# Comparing Two Lists of Same User Defined Type

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I've a dataset like this

```
cpeid                                cveid             LastEdited
cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_8.1:-      CVE-2015-0001   2017-01-28 17:03:21.197
cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_8:-        CVE-2015-0001   2017-01-28 17:03:21.197
cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_rt:-:gold  CVE-2015-0001   2017-01-28 17:03:21.197
```

and a backing entity like this:

```
public partial class cve_cpe
{
    [StringLength(250)]
    public string cpeid { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [StringLength(250)]
    public string cveid { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1, TypeName = "smalldatetime")]
    public DateTime LastEdited { get; set; }
}
```

I am using entityframework for basic crud on the database from a simple c# console application. Somewhere in the code I do this:

```
var mappings_to_add =  distinct_mappings_from_file
                      .Except(all_mappings, new cve_cpeComparer())
                      .ToList();
```

and my `IEqualityComparer` implementation is:

```
    class cve_cpeComparer : IEqualityComparer<cve_cpe>
    {
        public bool Equals(cve_cpe x, cve_cpe y)
        {
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, y))
                return true;
            if (x == null || y == null)
                return false;
            return x.cpeid == y.cpeid && x.cveid == y.cveid;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(cve_cpe obj)
        {
            return obj.cveid.GetHashCode() ^ obj.cpeid.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

but it won't simply work. I tried various suggestions on implementing GetHashCode, setting proper keys on entity and in db, manually removing duplicates from db, but it simply doesn't work. What am I missing here?

so basically, I expect the linq `.Except` to give me those entries from the list which don't already exist in db i.e. ignore the ones having same combination of `cveid` and `cpeid` already in db data list.

Interestingly enough, this thing works with so many other my user-defined types with their flavor of `IEqualityComparer` (implemented same logically), so wanted to know what I am doing wrong? Is it with the value of these strings with symbols?

**UPDATE**

So it works now, as it turns out, it was because of wrong pk configuration in the entity and modelbuilder, fixing which resolves the issue. 
But now I wanted to know why `LINQ .Except` even worry about primary key, specially when I am feeding it a custom `IEqualityComparer` ?

Comment: Are you tring to execute the except within the database (using EF query) or is executed in already materialized lists in the memory ?

Comment: it is being executed in `materialized list` in the memory

Comment: Your equality comparer considers `{ cpeid, cveid }` pair to be defining the uniqueness. But the entity PK (unique key) is `{ cveid, LastEdited }`. Apparently one of them is wrong and has to be corrected.

Comment: yes that was it, wrong pk configuration. it works now. Thanks, but can you please help me understand, why does it (linq-to-entity) even bother about PK? as I am working on in-memory detached list? I mean in the IEqualityComparer, I never care about PK

Comment: It works on your detached list. But the problem is that it makes wrong assumption for `mappings_to_add`, so I guess the issue is when you really try to add them to the database, and you get unique constraint violation. Or even when adding (attaching) them to the context because EF internally maintains unique key index in memory.

Comment: actually so inserting to db comes later, the output of the .Except was wrong list, so didn't let it go forward

Comment: i am curious too, does it hit any break points in the Comparer functions? I mean does it get executed even ?

Comment: @vasiloreshenski yes it goes in both of the methods i.e. `.Equals` and the `.GetHashCode`. I actually recorded the each time different objects were passed as x and y in equals and generated hashcode for each, wasn't really sure of the order though

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally end up in this page where the `IEqualityComparer.GetHashCode` implementation caught my attention. Imagine the following code:

```
var list = new List<cve_cpe>
{
    new cve_cpe { cpeid = "1", cveid = "2" },
    new cve_cpe { cpeid = "2", cveid = "1" }
};

var result = list.Except(list, new cve_cpeComparer()).ToList();
```

If you execute the above code, the `Equals` method will be invoked 4 times since the `GetHashCode` will return the same value for both objects. By changing the implementation of `GetHashCode`, this can be reduced to 2 times:

```
public int GetHashCode(cve_cpe obj)
{
    return obj.cveid.GetHashCode() * 11 /*Any prime number*/ ^ obj.cpeid.GetHashCode();
}
```